# How to execute root dependency from Yarn workspace with Zero Install and PnP

Tags: yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I'm trying to setup a monorepo with Yarn Workspaces, Zero Install + PnP (no node_modules, but instead a .yarn/cache inside the root).

Since I don't want to define dependencies such as typescript inside all my workspaces, I want to add it just 1 time in the package.json at the root.

But if I do that, I get `'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I know I could just install it globally on my pc, but I think it used to work with yarn when it was node_modules and I really want to use the typescript version that I defined in the root package.json file.

Let's assume this folder structure

```
- .yarn/cache (where all dependencies are stored as .zip files)
- package.json (where typescript is defined)
  -  packages/package-a (when inside, I need to be able to reference "tsc")
```

When inside packages/package-a (or when writing `yarn workspace package-a build`, how can I use "tsc" in my build script for that package? The tsc defined in the root package.json - instead of "tsc" can i supply a path to the binary, or how does it work without node_modules binaries?

Using `"packageManager": "yarn@3.2.1"` as defined in the root package.json

Comment: I had the same question; I really thought I read somewhere (and had experienced in years past) that top level devDependency commands (tsc for typescript, for example) are available in app workspaces… But experimentally, they are not, in a brand new trivial example project. Have you spotted any documentation promising these will be available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your root workspace is "my-monorepo" (ie. the "name" property in "package.json"), you could do something like this in "package-a/package.json"

```json
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn workspace my-monorepo tsc -b packages/package-a/tsconfig.json"
  }
}
```

Of course this is not limited to "typescript", but something you can do for all (dev)Dependencies inside your root "package.json".

With that said I wouldn't recommend doing it this way. Instead, keep things centralized. Create a scripts folder at the root level and write a build script that builds/lints/tests one/all package(s).

If you plan on having lots of packages it might be worth looking into Bazel instead. Bazel will make sure only changed packages is rebuilt, so you don't need to build each individual package.

Comment: This does reach out to use that dependency from the top level package, but it also runs the command in that context (directory), rather than in the context of the specific workspace. I wonder if the intended way to do this is to duplicate all your needed dependencies in each workspace’s package.json.

Comment: One advantage of monorepos is centralization, so I don't think local build, lint and test scripts in each package makes much sense. To be able to execute each of them locally each package would need to define its own devDependencies - or reference the roots devDeps like in my answer above.
Of course you can do it that way, but I'd recommend making a scripts folder and writing a build script that would either build all packages or specific packages (you can pass arguments like this `yarn build -- --packages=<paths_to_packages>` and access them with `process.argv` from inside the script